# Income from dividends and rental

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, dividends

My total income for this tax year is £5600 from share dividends and £6000 from rental income, i.e., £11600 should I be filling out a tax return or some such. Or am I one of the people who is completely removed from the tax system? I have no other income and I am confused. Should I be making a disclosure?

Comment: I assume you're in the UK given the £ symbols. Just to check, are you saying you don't have any other income at all, i.e. no employment income?

Comment: Hi Yes I guess i`ve kind of dropped out for the past 3 years so yes tha`ts the income I have savings i`m 55 and always been paye up till then thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The gov.uk site includes a brief test to [check if you need to send a self-assessment tax return.](https://www.gov.uk/check-if-you-need-tax-return)

According to the information you have provided, you do need to send a return.

This issue appears to be that you have over GBP2,500 of rental income from a property you own.

Your gross income is only GBP100 over the current annual income tax allowance, so it is unlikely you will have to pay more than a few quid.